# NSMutableArray addObject overwrites data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am adding an object "m" to `NSMutableArray` as follows:

```
    [m setObject:a forKey:@"a"];
    [m setObject:b forKey:@"b"];
    [m setObject:c forKey:@"c"];
    [m setObject:d forKey:@"d"];

    [myArray addObject:m];

    [m release];
```

For one object it works fine, but when another objects are added, same values are repeated for all the objects in myArray.

How to avoid this?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you doing this in a for loop ?

Comment: The code you posted is fine. You'll need to provide more code and error example if you want a solution.

Comment: No not in for loop, because first time my data is inserted on button click.. later it is inserted after data is received from server and notification to update screen is received.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a separate instance of `NSMUtablearray` each time you populate and insert it, otherwise you keep re-using the same instance, so only the last state of it appears in each position of the array.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *m = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    // Presumably, this part is done differently on each iteration
    [m setObject:a forKey:@"a"];
    [m setObject:b forKey:@"b"];
    [m setObject:c forKey:@"c"];
    [m setObject:d forKey:@"d"];
    [myArray addObject:m];
}
```

Comment: I think he can also do [myArray addObject:[m mutableCopy]]; to avoid the same pointer problem

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu That's another way to avoid the problem. There should be no call of `release` on each insertion, though - it should be released once, after the loop is over.

Comment: I have tried allocating new instance every time,but same issue

Comment: Oops...Allocated the memory again, cleaned the code and ran again...this time it worked like a charm! Great thanks all ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* m = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[m setObject:@"1" forKey:@"a"];
[m setObject:@"2" forKey:@"b"];
[m setObject:@"3" forKey:@"c"];
[m setObject:@"4" forKey:@"d"];

NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:m];

NSLog(@"%@", m);
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```